# Opportunity product search testclass is getting assertion error

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage, failing-tests, code

I am getting error while running Apex Test Execution

System.AssertException: Assertion Failed
Class.opportunityProductEntryTests.theTests: line 80, column 1

Below is the test class

```
@istest(seeAllData =True)
private class opportunityProductEntryTests {

    static testMethod void theTests(){

        // You really should create test data, but I'm going to query instead
        // It's my best shot of avoiding a test failure in most orgs
        // Once you've installed this package though, you might want to write your own tests
        // or at least customize these ones to make them more applicable to your org

OpportunityLineItem oli = [select Id, PricebookEntryId, PricebookEntry.Pricebook2Id, PricebookEntry.Name, PriceBookEntry.Product2Id, OpportunityId, Opportunity.AccountId from OpportunityLineItem limit 1];


        ////////////////////////////////////////
        //  testopportunityProductEntry
        ////////////////////////////////////////

        // load the page       
PageReference pageRef = Page.opportunityProductEntry;
pageRef.getParameters().put('Id',oli.OpportunityId);
Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);

        // load the extension
opportunityProductEntryExtension oPEE = new opportunityProductEntryExtension(new ApexPages.StandardController(oli.Opportunity));

        // test 'getChosenCurrency' method
if(UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrganization())
System.assert(oPEE.getChosenCurrency()!='');
        else
System.assertEquals(oPEE.getChosenCurrency(),'');

        // we know that there is at least one line item, so we confirm
        Integer startCount = oPEE.ShoppingCart.size();
system.assert(startCount>0);

        //test search functionality without finding anything
oPEE.searchString = 'michaelforce is a hip cat';
oPEE.updateAvailableList();
system.assert(oPEE.AvailableProducts.size()==0);

        //test remove from shopping cart
oPEE.toUnselect = oli.PricebookEntryId;
oPEE.removeFromShoppingCart();
system.assert(oPEE.shoppingCart.size()==startCount-1);

        //test save and reload extension
oPEE.onSave();
oPEE = new opportunityProductEntryExtension(new ApexPages.StandardController(oli.Opportunity));
system.assert(oPEE.shoppingCart.size()==startCount-1);

        // test search again, this time we will find something
oPEE.searchString = oli.PricebookEntry.Name;
oPEE.updateAvailableList();
system.assert(oPEE.AvailableProducts.size()>0);       

        // test add to Shopping Cart function
oPEE.toSelect = oPEE.AvailableProducts[0].Id;
oPEE.addToShoppingCart();
system.assert(oPEE.shoppingCart.size()==startCount);

        // test save method - WITHOUT quanitities and amounts entered and confirm that error message is displayed
oPEE.onSave();
system.assert(ApexPages.getMessages().size()>0);

        // add required info and try save again
for(OpportunityLineItem o : oPEE.ShoppingCart){
o.quantity = 5;
o.unitprice = 300;
        }
oPEE.onSave();

        // query line items to confirm that the save worked
opportunityLineItem[] oli2 = [select Id from opportunityLineItem where OpportunityId = :oli.OpportunityId];
//system.assert(oli2.size()==startCount);

        // test on new Opp (no pricebook selected) to make sure redirect is happening
        Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity(Name='New Opp',stageName='Pipeline',Amount=10,closeDate=System.Today()+30,AccountId=oli.Opportunity.AccountId);
        insert(newOpp);
oPEE = new opportunityProductEntryExtension(new ApexPages.StandardController(newOpp));
System.assert(oPEE.priceBookCheck()!=null);

        // final quick check of cancel button
System.assert(oPEE.onCancel()!=null);


        ////////////////////////////////////////
        //  test redirect page
        ////////////////////////////////////////

        // load the page
pageRef = Page.opportunityProductRedirect;
pageRef.getParameters().put('Id',oli2[0].Id);
Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);

        // load the extension and confirm that redirect function returns something
opportunityProductRedirectExtension oPRE = new opportunityProductRedirectExtension(new ApexPages.StandardController(oli2[0]));
System.assert(oPRE.redirect()!=null);

    }
}
```

Comment: Any help to resolve this error and increase code coverage is appreciated.

Comment: line 80 is  `System.assert(oPEE.priceBookCheck()!=null);` so the problem is in that method or the way you've set up data for that method

Comment: public PageReference changePricebook(){
    
        // This simply returns a PageReference to the standard Pricebook selection screen
        // Note that is uses retURL parameter to make sure the user is sent back after they choose
    
        PageReference ref = new PageReference('/oppitm/choosepricebook.jsp');
        ref.getParameters().put('id',theOpp.Id);
        ref.getParameters().put('retURL','/apex/opportunityProductEntry?id=' + theOpp.Id);
        
        return ref;
    }

Comment: The above is the method in the class. Because of  one line System.assert(oPEE.priceBookCheck()!=null); I am getting error . Please help to resolve this. very very urgent .. I need to deploy to production because of this error I got stuck , If i am commenting I am losing my code coverage even though test class pass

Comment: sai -- please use [edit] to amend your question with the method you posed in a comment; Community etiquette is not to post additional code in comments